# How can I fix my Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.6.5 that won't start?

Tags: hortonworks-sandbox

Its is loading for more than hour but no change. Can anyone help me with the installation of Hortonworks Sandbox
[image]

I did not find anything related to my problem. Storage is given 8Gb. I have tried to reset the sandbox but no change.